# Included layout -> how to populate

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, include

I included an menu_bar.xml in every layout for every activity except LoginActivity area.

I need to populate the menu_bar with the realName in the leftside and receive messages.

How do I populate the textView in order to keep the data in all the other Activities?

I tried to make a BaseActivity and extend it in the other Activities, but populates just once, in other activities comes back to the default value of the textView.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
XApplication xApplication;
TextView realName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    xApplication=(XApplication)getApplication();
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_bar);
    realName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.realName);
    realName.setText(Preferences.getInstance().getString(Constants.REAL_NAME,""));

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: when launching other activity, the layout will be inflated again. you have to populate it again, so inheritance could solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a common layout for your base activity. and then include that layout in all the layout using the  tagwhich you want to make the same.

After that create one Abstract Activity and then handle all the click of the buttons and code in this activity and then extends this activity in all other activity in which you have include the base layout.

For example

common buttons xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tabhost_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_btn_active" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/label_home"
        style="@style/bottom_tab_btn"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSetting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_btn_active" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/label_settings"
        style="@style/bottom_tab_btn"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_btn_active" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/label_more"
        style="@style/bottom_tab_btn"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a xml layout in which you can include above XML file

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/bottom_bar" />
```

Here android:layout_width and android:layout_height and layout are compulsory attributes

Now here is a Base Activity which handles the click of the common controls

```
public abstract class BottomBar extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected Button btnHome;
    Button btnSetting, btnMore;
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActivity = this;
    }

    protected void mappingWidgets() {

        btnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
        btnSetting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetting);
        btnMore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMore);

        btnHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSetting.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMore.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == null)
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "You are refering null object. "
                            + "Please check weather you had called super class method mappingWidgets() or not");
        if (v == btnHome) {

        } else if (v == btnSetting) {

        }else if(v == btnMore) {

        }
    }

    protected void handleBackgrounds(View v) {
        if (v == btnHome) {
            btnHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_hover);
            btnSetting.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_active);
            btnMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_active);

        } else if (v == btnSetting) {
            btnHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_active);
            btnSetting.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_hover);
            btnMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_active);

        } else if (v == btnMore) {
            btnHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_active);
            btnSetting.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_active);
            btnMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_btn_hover);
        }
    }

}
```

Now one step is remaining to extends this Base activity in all your activities.

You can extends the Base activity in activity using the extends keyword. For example

```
public class MyActivity extends BottomBar
```

Note: From the child activity you must have to call the super method of the base class to handle the click of the common controls of your base layout.

You can thus implement multiple common layout within your single activity.

Hope this will help you. Enjoy!!

CREDIT: [How to create a generic Android XML layout for all activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994957/how-to-create-a-generic-android-xml-layout-for-all-activities)

Comment: I already did this for buttons, but i have a TextView to populate and doesn't have information persistence, like when I switch to next Activity the values are lost...

Comment: The textView will not be persistent because though you are including the same xml file in different activities but there context are same. You have to pass the value using intent/bundle then repopulate in the textView of the new activity.

Comment: Can be implemented with fragments?